# Chrome extension: how to programmatically inspect extension's background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How does one programmatically open the Developer Tools window of a Chrome extension's background page using the Chrome Extensions API?

Essentially, I'm looking to achieve the programmatic equivalent of manually clicking on the "inspect background page" link of a given Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

I don't think there is a way to do it; Google's own app, [Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc), uses a **private** API for this:

```js
// Opens the devtools inspect window for the page.
chrome.developerPrivate.inspect({
  extension_id: String(item.id),
  render_process_id: String(view.render_process_id),
  render_view_id: String(view.render_view_id),
  incognito: view.incognito,
});
```

Obviously, this only works in specially-whitelisted apps and extensions.

Comment: that's a shame! Thanks all the same.